# PHP JSON array from query

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json

I'm not a php developer, but trying to get an array within an array from this query:

SELECT distinct d.DiscussionId as DiscussionId, d.AvatarId as AvatarId, d.Heading as Heading, d.body as Body, c.commentid as CommentId, c.userid as UserId, c.comment as Comment
FROM Discussion AS d
INNER JOIN Comments AS c ON d.discussionid = c.discussionid
WHERE    d.DiscussionId = c.DiscussionId

The JSON output is:

```
[
    {
        "DiscussionId": "1", 
        "AvatarId": null, 
        "Heading": "New discussion heading", 
        "Body": "This is the discussion body", 
        "Comments": [
            {
                "DiscussionId": "1", 
                "CommentId": "1", 
                "UserId": "2", 
                "Comment": "This is a comment i made"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "DiscussionId": "1", 
        "AvatarId": null, 
        "Heading": "New discussion heading", 
        "Body": "This is the discussion body", 
        "Comments": [
            {
                "DiscussionId": "1", 
                "CommentId": "2", 
                "UserId": "2", 
                "Comment": "This is a second comment"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I need is to nest all Comments in one Discussion.

the php code is below, no error but not giving the output i want, for each discussion there maybe several comments so i need DiscussionId:1 displayed only once with multilple comments array

```
$result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);



 $model = array();
 $record = -1;
 $currentWeID = -1;    
 while($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
 $record++;
 $model[] = array();
 $model[$record]['DiscussionId'] = $e['DiscussionId']; 
 $model[$record]['AvatarId'] = $e['AvatarId']; 
 $model[$record]['Heading'] = $e['Heading'];
 $model[$record]['Body'] = $e['Body']; 
 $model[$record]['Comments'][] = array( 

 'DiscussionId'=> $e['DiscussionId'], 
 'CommentId' => $e['CommentId'], 
 'UserId' => $e['UserId'], 
 'Comment' => $e['Comment'] 
 ); 

}


print json_encode ($model);
```

Comment: Post code from what you have tried and what errors it is causing.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

Added Disscussion Id as an index for the array, should work for you. Just off the top of my head, not tested.

```
$result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);
$model = array();
 $record = -1;
 $currentWeID = -1;
 $model = array(); 

 while($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
 $record++;
 $model[$e['DiscussionId']][$record]['AvatarId'] = $e['AvatarId']; 
 $model[$e['DiscussionId']][$record]['Heading'] = $e['Heading'];
 $model[$e['DiscussionId']][$record]['Body'] = $e['Body']; 
 $model[$e['DiscussionId']][$record]['Comments'][] = array( 

 'DiscussionId'=> $e['DiscussionId'], 
 'CommentId' => $e['CommentId'], 
 'UserId' => $e['UserId'], 
 'Comment' => $e['Comment'] 
 ); 

}


print json_encode ($model);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, it's looking closer but only returns the second comment for the discussion

Comment: @user3550256 try now, I had left `$model = array();` inside the while loop by mistake

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting many `comments` from a single `dicussion`.
You should overwrite that variable instead of creating a new element at each iteration:

```
 $model = array();  
 while($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
 //We overwrite the same variable, that's ok
 $model['DiscussionId'] = $e['DiscussionId']; 
 $model['AvatarId'] = $e['AvatarId']; 
 $model['Heading'] = $e['Heading'];
 $model['Body'] = $e['Body']; 
 //Only comments would be an array
 $model['Comments'][] = array( 
        'DiscussionId'=> $e['DiscussionId'], 
        'CommentId' => $e['CommentId'], 
        'UserId' => $e['UserId'], 
        'Comment' => $e['Comment'] 
        ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);

```
 $model = array();
 $record = 0;
 $currentWeID = -1;    
 while($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
 $model[] = array();
 $model[$record][$e['DiscussionId']]['AvatarId'] = $e['AvatarId']; 
 $model[$record][$e['DiscussionId']]['Heading'] = $e['Heading'];
 $model[$record][$e['DiscussionId']]['Body'] = $e['Body']; 
 $model[$record][$e['DiscussionId']]['Comments'][] = array( 
    'DiscussionId'=> $e['DiscussionId'], 
    'CommentId' => $e['CommentId'], 
    'UserId' => $e['UserId'], 
    'Comment' => $e['Comment'] 
    ); ;
 $record++;
}


print json_encode ($model);
```

This might help you.  Dont forget to accept answer if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible with just changing the SQL query: you need to change the server-side code (PHP, as I understand) which transorms query results to JSON.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer.